# Getting the following error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'InviteUser' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Am adding functionality to an existing app which is using Angular 1.5.7 along with Typescript, I haven't used either of these technologies before and have ran into a dead end.

I'm receiving the following error ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'InviteUser' of undefined***

Here's my code.

**AddEditContactController.ts**

```
import CT = require('../../models/commontypes');
import E = require('../../models/Employers');
import * as Common from "../../../common/commonapp";
import EmployerService = require('../services/EmployerService');

class AddEditContactController {
    static controllerId = 'addEditContact';
    static $inject = ['$uibModalInstance', '$routeParams', '$http', Common.LookupService.serviceId, 'Item' ];

    public InviteSent: boolean = false;
    public OrganisationID: number;

    constructor(protected $modalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance,
        private $routeParams: E.Employed.IViewEmployerProfesionalBodyRouteParams,
        protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
        private LookupService: Common.LookupService,
        public Item: E.Employed.Contact,
        private EmployerService: EmployerService)
        {
            this.OrganisationID = +$routeParams.EmployerID; 
        }

    public Cancel() {
        this.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    public Save(form) {
        if (form.$valid) {
            //don't need to pass anything back because the same instance we passed in will have been manipulated
            this.$modalInstance.close(this.Item);
        }
    }

    public SendContactInvite(form) {
        if (form.$valid) {
            this.EmployerService.InviteUser(this.Item.ID, this.OrganisationID).then(() => {  // The Error is pointing to this line 
                this.InviteSent = true;
            });
        }
    } 

}

    export = AddEditContactController;
```

The error is pointing to the line within the SendContactInvite function, both the ItemID and OrganisationID contain a value though, Am I missing something?

Here is the rest

**EmployerService.ts**

```
  InviteUser(ContactID: number, OrganisationID: number): ng.IHttpPromise<{}> {
        return this.$http({
            url: '/employer/InviteUser',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                ContactID: ContactID,
                OrganisationID: OrganisationID 
            }
        });
    }
```

**AddEditContact.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="pull-right  ng-scope">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-employed" ng-click="modal.SendContactInvite(form)" ng-disabled="form.$invalid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true" uib-tooltip="Invite contact to become a member" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></span> Send Invite</button>
  </div>
```

Any help / advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: This is likely because the `this` in the scope of execution isn't what you think it is. Try to do this in your `AddEditContactController` ctor: `this. SendContactInvite = this. SendContactInvite.bind(this);`. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Nope.. I still received the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify what should be injected on the class you did not specify `EmployerService`

```
static $inject = [
  '$uibModalInstance', 
  '$routeParams', 
  '$http', 
  Common.LookupService.serviceId, 
  'Item'
];
```

You will need to add it to the list of injected items:

```
static $inject = [
  '$uibModalInstance', 
  '$routeParams', 
  '$http', 
  Common.LookupService.serviceId, 
  'Item',
  'EmployerService' // <---- NEW!!!
];
```

Comment: I've tried to do this but it causes the button responsible to open this view to stop working on-click, I also tried to add `EmployerService.serviceId` in replace of "EmployerService"

Comment: Your suggestion worked when adding `EmployerService.serviceID`. There was also an issue with the line at the top `import EmployerService = require('../services/EmployerService');` which was pointing to the incorrect path but displaying no error. Thanks